# How to stop registration emails from going to spam?

Tags: members, email, registration

I have an EE site with 30-50 daily registrations.  We're noticing that a lot of the registration confirmation emails are going to spam folders lately (through testing and user reports, along with a lot of non-spam pending members).  I've tried running the email both through php mail and SMTP, with similar results.  This isn't a major area of expertise for me, so I'm hoping some of you have suggestions for how to reduce the chance that these automated emails end up in someones spam folder.

Comment: I'm also noticing that more emails are ending up in spam w/ SMTP than php mail, which is backwards from what I've been told should happen.

Comment: even my registration emails are ending in spam folders. Did you guys had any success in getting the emails delivered to the Inbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve been down this road a number of times, and have even had problems with emails originating out of an EngineHosting server while email was handled through Google Apps.

There’s probably a problem between what your server is reporting its address as and what your email that’s being generated says its from. I would highly recommend moving all transactional emails to the very excellent [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) service from MailChimp. You can even authenticate so that the emails show up as verified for that domain. The service is free up to 12,000 transactional emails a month, so you probably won’t need to even pay for the service.

If you’d like to automate it a bit, you could also check out ObjectiveHTML’s awesome [Postmaster addon](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster). It does much of what Mandrill does, but makes it quite a bit easier, and he’s always adding awesome things to it.

Comment: Mandrill looks like a good option here, I'll give it a shot and hope it works better!

Comment: SendGrid is a nice alternative to Mandrill that works well, too: http://sendgrid.com/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the hit list I would go down:

- Check the email addresses on outgoing messages (Admin -> Email Configuration AND Members -> Preferences). The shopping carts that set up member accounts have additional settings.
- Learn about the SPF (Sender Policy Framework) DNS records which notify other mail servers of who may send mail from your domain. [GoDaddy has a tutorial](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7926/adding-or-editing-spf-records?locale=en), and you can find others around.
- Make sure that your hosting provider (the IP sending messages) has not been blacklisted by some spam service. If this has happened, you might end up with email messages bounced back to you which explain how to get taken off the list.